# (OCR) Tesseract not recognizing simple digits

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using PyTesseract to extract information from multiple images which contain vertically separated prices (one price per line), horizontally aligned to the right like the following image:

[image]

Tesseract is not able to extract reliable text with such image, so, image processing has to occur:

- Image scaling to 4x;
- Binarization
- "Bolding";
- Gaussian blur;

Which results in the following image:

[image]

Pytesseract is successfully able to extract its information (**using PSM --6**) resulting in a string containing:

```
96,000,000
94,009,999
90,000,000
85,000,000
78,000,000
70,000,000
66,000,000
```

However, when Pytesseract is presented with some edge cases like an image with a single digit, recognition fails. Example:
Pre-processed:

[image]

post-processed:

[image]

Which results in an empty string extracted. This is strange as the number 8 was previously successfully read. What other suggestions should I follow? I've spent endless hours trying to optimize the algorythm without success for such case scenarios.

Comment: Very well written question, but you should also include some code in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I had tried the same exact scenario with easyocr. Easyocr is also using tesseract engine internally for optical character recognition. I try with resizing image of custom size (600,600) and fed to easyocr, it worked.

```
import easyocr
import cv2


image = cv2.imread('7.png')
image = cv2.resize(image,(600,600))
cv2.imwrite('image.png',image)
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
result = reader.readtext('image.png')
texts = [detection[1] for detection in result if detection[2] > 0.5]
print(texts)
```

The output for first image is,

```
['96,000,000', '94,009,999', '90,000,000', '85,000,000', '78,000,000', '70,000,000', '66,000,000']
```

The output for second image is,

```
['8']
```

May be this alternate solution work for your case. You can install easyocr by`pip install easyocr`. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

**Crop the region you want to recognize**

Add this line after init

> baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseApi.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, "0123456789");

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).